# Possible to compile Library project as external JAR?

Tags: android, jar

More than 2 years ago, distinguished members of this community mentioned that in the future, it will be possible to export Android library project as external JAR.

Is it still not possible to do that or I missed the big news?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it still not possible to do that

Correct.

The direction now is to generate an AAR file, used by the new Gradle-based build system. The [AAR file will contain compiled code, plus resources and other stuff](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format).

Comment: AAR file? That is why everyone stopped talking about JAR. I had to idea they moved to another direction. Thanks.

Comment: @sandalone: As a bonus, we get an all-new source of joke material for International Talk Like a Pirate Day! :-)